# java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Project Directory structure

[image]

External jar files

[image]

I am working on a basic hibernate program.

Player.java:

```
package com.to;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity

@Table
public class Player {
    
    @Id
    private int playerId;
    private String playerName; 
    private int age;
    private String teamName;
    
    public Player(int playerId, String playerName, int age, String teamName) {
        super();
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.age = age;
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [playerId=" + playerId + ", playerName=" + playerName + ", age=" + age + ", teamName=" + teamName
                + "]";
    } 
    
    public Player() {
        
    }   

}
```

HibernateMain.java:

```
package com.control;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.to.Player;

public class HibernateMain {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.to.Player.class);
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = 
                    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Player p1 = new Player(10,"Amit",30,"India");
        session.save(p1);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 ~ Hibernate Search, full-text search for your domain model
 ~
 ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later
 ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:1521/simplilearn_db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">scott</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hr</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">target/indexes</property>
        <mapping class="org.hibernate.search.test.spatial.POI"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am encountering errors

```
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
Mar 16, 2023 1:08:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment \<clinit\>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 16, 2023 1:08:26 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector \<clinit\>
SEVERE: null
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,\[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.\<clinit\>(Injector.java:197)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.\<init\>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.\<init\>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.\<init\>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.\<init\>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
at com.control.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,\[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2227)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:201)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
... 33 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object\[\])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:311)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:97)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.\<init\>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.\<init\>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.\<init\>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.\<init\>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
at com.control.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:14)
```

Since I'm new to this technology, I have no idea about the errors listed.

I tried adding jaxb-2.3.0 jar files jaxb-runtime jar file to clear this out but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You should include the libraries into your exported jar. I suggest you to use maven/gradle system to do this. You can also check for option to export them too but idk if it will works fine. You can also include in path at runtime thanks to command param

Comment: May I know what do you mean by exported jar...since, I've already added libraries and external jars in build path...
Also I'm not using maven/gradle since it's a basic hibernate program

Comment: You are running everything directly from eclipse console ? If yes, sorry but the exported jar thing isn't for you

Comment: Yes, I am running from eclipse

Comment: Ok, so I suggest you to check for eclipse config and be sure it's running with good java version for example

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below dependency for hibernate version 5.4.24 (
earlier I had 5.2.11) changing to JRE - 11 and also by fixing the project structure with maven clears the error

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.24.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also adding the below dependencies for jaxb and mysql connector helps...

```
 
    <!-- Mysql Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```